# Passing a PHP $_POST array to javascript/jQuery to send back to PHP via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, post

I need to pass the `$_POST` array currently available on the page into my javascript.
jQuery needs to `$.post` this array back to php and get it processed.

I've tried the below and my jquery and post is fine but my `echo $items;` is drawing a blank on receipt on the php side.

any ideas please?

**php**:

```
$items = json_encode($_POST);
```

**jquery**:

```
var data = {
'action': 'someaction',
'items': <?php echo $items;?>
 } ;

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    console.log( response ) ;
});
```

I'm expecting the `$_POST` array to be passed via `$.post` in jquery back to my php function.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. There won't be anything in `$_POST` until the ajax sends something unless there is also a form involved that was previously submitted. If there is indeed a form then you wouldn't need to use the secondary ajax at all

Comment: Why do you plant to play tennis with some datas ? You have your `$_POST` on server, treat it. Don't send it back to client to re-send it to server

Comment: maybe `var data = {'action': 'someaction', 'items': '<?php echo $items;?>' } ;`

Comment: @anon that looks identical to what OP already has

Comment: @charlietfl just adding single quote before echoing $items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i've found an answer.

The line i'm missing is:

```
<?php echo "var items = " . $items . ";" ;?>
```

so this works for me:

```
**PHP**
$items = json_encode( $_POST ) ;

**JS**
var items;
<?php echo "var items = " . $items . ";" ;?>
```

Yes a form was already submitted....so ihave to capture what was submitted. Timeouts occur on server side so i compare what was posted with what has been brought back... i use ajax to process the two. Messy. But if i find a better solution i'll use it.